# Implement docking on wpf MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit and Dragablz

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have been using the excellent [MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit). I have followed the example [MahMaterialDragablzMashUp](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/tree/master/MahMaterialDragablzMashUp).

Looking at the example, it allows you to drag and drop but does not allow docking. I have been trying to implement this without success.
I followed the guide [InterTabClient](http://dragablz.net/2014/11/18/getting-started-with-dragablz-tabablzcontrol/).

Would it be possible to post an example of docking using the intertabclient?

Thanks,

Comment: Hi, have you looked at the Layout control which is part of Dragablz? This allows docking (but not in your classic IDE sense). If you download the Dragablz source project from GitHub you can see it in action.